# libmproxy issue - 'module' object has no attribute 'TLSv1_1_METHOD'

Tags: python-2.7, mitmproxy, libmproxy

I tried to use Libmproxy with my linux RHEL 7, got the following exception:

```
    from libmproxy import controller, proxy
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libmproxy/proxy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .primitives import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libmproxy/proxy/primitives.py", line 2, in <module>
    from netlib import socks, tcp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netlib/socks.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import tcp, utils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netlib/tcp.py", line 62, in <module>
    "TLSv1_1": (SSL.TLSv1_1_METHOD, SSL_BASIC_OPTIONS),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TLSv1_1_METHOD'
```

Already tried to reinstall mitmproxy, netlib, PyOpenSSL and Cryptography.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very outdated version of OpenSSL installed on your system. Update OpenSSL/libssl and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your fault. The version of OpenSSL you are using is compiled with TLSv1.1 support removed. It's a bug in mitmproxy that it assumes  `SSL.TLSv1_1_METHOD` is available.